# How to map desired data from an array of objects and return two new objects containing those values

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

How i can extract just the desired data from an array of objects and assign to two new objects,
example below:

```
const sourceObject = {
 key1: "value1",
 key2: "value2",
 sourceArray: [{
   cost: 10,
   time: 30,
   shift: 1,
   description: "text",
   name: "John"
 }]
}
```

i want to extract cost & description from the source and assign to the two new objects, to get this as the final result:

```
firstNewObject = {
  cost: 10,
  description: "text"
}

secondNewObject = {
  cost: 10,
  description: "text"
}
```

tried this:

```
const firstNewObject = secondNewObject = sourceObject.sourceArray.map(({cost, description}) => ({cost, description }));
```

it works but returns 2 new arrays with an object containing cost & description

i need to display the value for cost like firstNewObject.cost
what is the best way with ES6? thank you

Comment: Why are you mapping? There's just one element, and you want to copy its properties into two objects.

Comment: Note that `const var1 = var2 = expression` does *not* declare `var2`. It's an undeclared global variable.

Comment: Can `sourceArray` contain more than one element? What should the result be in that case?

Comment: Even if it did work to declare them in a chain it would assign a single object reference to both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of any nice shortcut. Just create two objects containing the desired properties from the array element.

```
const element = ourceObject.sourceArray[0];
const firstNewObject = {cost: element.cost, description: element.description};
const secondNewObject = {cost: element.cost, description: element.description};
```

Comment: @pilchard I think I'll just leave it as is. It's simple enough and not cryptic.

Comment: I did consider `const secondNewObject = structuredClone(firstNewObject);`